# ZXING mobile issue with repeat scanning

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using the zing mobile scanner and it works well however I am calling the same action from a different button and it's refusing to scan it brings up the preview window ok but won't invoke the scan.

```
public async  void  BtnScanStockTakeItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    

     var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
     scanPage.ToggleTorch();
     scanPage.IsScanning = true;               
     await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
     scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
     {


      // Stop scanning
      scanPage.IsScanning = false;

      // Pop the page and show the result
      Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

I am then calling the above from another button method lets say the saved function

```
private async void SaveFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        foreach (var item in transferList)
        {

            int z = await restServices.PostStockTakeTransaction(item);
        }
        Preferences.Set("StockTakeWarehouse", pickStockTake.SelectedIndex);
        WarehouseName = pickStockTake.SelectedItem.ToString();
        bool x = await DisplayAlert("Test", "Item Saved", "ReScan", "Cancel");
        if (x)
        {
             BtnScanStockTakeItem_Clicked(sender, e);
            //this is where it rescans the item
        }
 }
```

String thing is I am getting no logcat errors or nothing the viewport of the scanner shows but just won't accept the scan some reason same barcode format as before.

Comment: could you share a test demo ?it works on my side.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT what version of it are you using what works u havent explained

Comment: i use version 2.4.1.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I fixed the problem I had to invoke a new thread there it was because the camera was being locked to the last thread for some reason

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who faces a simlar problem it was the fact my camera thread was not properly called I had to do

```
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
 {
      BtnScanStockTakeItem_Clicked(sender, e);
 });
```

Works as expected